# Android app crashes when I have converted my MainActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmenttransaction

I decided to extend my `MainActivity` class to a `Fragment` and now my app crashes (doesn't even load - see stack trace below).

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

Button login;
EditText username;
EditText password;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    loginButtonOnClick();
    return view;
}

private void loginButtonOnClick(){
    Button loginButtons = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButtons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment userPage = new UserPage();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.mainGUI, userPage);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is my `xml` file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/passwordLogin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/loginButtonName"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:focusable="true" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/loginMain"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the stack trace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{lukazs.newapps/lukazs.newapps.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: lukazs.newapps.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: lukazs.newapps.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have to use
This is where I am having severe difficulty, I can't use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` as I can't call this fragment from the main activity so I have to use `android.app.Fragment`. Problem is `getFragmentManager` belongs to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dbusers, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) getView().findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsAdapter(getFragmentManager())); // getFragmentManager() can't be called.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind these two points:

1.There has to be 1 Activity in an App.(Fragment is an Activity which can exist only at the top of Any activity)

2.Pass `this` or `ActivityName.this` instead of `getApplicatonContext()` - Usually resolves this **Error**

> MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Alternatively what you can do is Make a `Fragment layout` along with its `Fragment Class` and Add it to your **MainActivity** XML layout.

Extend the `Fragment Class` to `Fragment` with an `onCreateView` method.

And add your **Fragment Layout** Dynamically here.For more info you can check my [Github repo showing Adding fragments with Java Dynamically](https://github.com/CandleCoder/FragmentWithJava)

Comment: Now I am getting an error for `getFragmentManager()` because I am using `import android.app.Fragment;` Do you know how to resolve this

Comment: use getFragmentManager() in your MainActivity for fragment Transaction like I did here https://github.com/CandleCoder/FragmentWithJava/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/magicsw/fragmentwithjava/MainActivity.java

Comment: Please check my updated Post. It is the code at the bottom

Comment: Just follow my github repo its very basic and easy you wl sort out your problem...You need to understand the correct flow...You are not getting it right...

Answer (score 0):

The official Android documentation has a simple sample you can look at here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Use the `Download the Sample` button to get them whole sample.

Here is another link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Summary:

Your MainActivity should still be an activity.  In the layout file, you have a placeholder for your fragments.

When you Activity is up and running, you create the fragment and put it into the placeholder.

Then there are a variety of functions to put different fragments into the placeholder spot, and move forward and backwards, just like activities.

Comment: Now I am getting an error for `getFragmentManager()` because I am using `import android.app.Fragment;` Do you know how to resolve this

Comment: You don't appear to have updated your code at all, to show the changes you have made.   My only recommendation at this point is to continue to read Google's android documentation and guides.  I have added another link to my post.

Comment: @LukazsPioetrszci the link I added states "You can get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity like this:"

Answer (score -1):

Checkout your AndroidManifest.xml and remove all messages about MainActivity!